How to find duplicate values in one column while checking if a condition in another column is met
I work on a table with some cells, the value in "E" might be repeated once or more, but depending on the date value in column "H", I need to get specific text. But, I don't know how to write the formula.
What I need to do is:
IF) TOW CELLS HAVE THE SAME VALUE IN COLUMN"E" AND $H>TODAY(),"Valid Stream"
I wrote this formula, but it doesn't work:
IF(AND($E5=E:E,$H5>TODAY(),"Valid Stream"))
I don't need to check only "E5", but if any cell in column "E" is repeated, and because it might be repeated many times, I need to control that with the date in "H" if it's bigger than today().
"E5" is the first cell in the table.


Well, obviously the first part of the and() must be true as E5 must equal E5. So check the detail of H5 - I suggest you test it separately.

At first glance, you have the closing brackets in the wrong place. You have if(and(a, b, result)) but it should be if(and(a, b), true_result, false_result)

@MatBailie thank you you are right but actually I donr mean exactly cell E5 but if any cell in the coulmn E equal any other cell in the same coulmn

@Ramadan Are you looking for =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH($E5,$E$6:$E$1000,0)),$H5>TODAY()),"Valid Stream","")?

@Ramadan Can you post a screenshot your your sheet? What error do you get?

@Harun24hr done - screenshot added

@Ramadan I do not see any screenshot.

@Harun24hr it's ok now

@Ramadan I believe, your H column data are not true date value. They are just string enter as date. Can you please ensure it?

@Harun24hr Yes i'm sure that H cell is set as date  but just customed format yy.mm.dd

@Harun24hr  =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH($E5,$E$6:$E$1000,0)),$H5>TODAY()),"Valid Stream","") this works perfectly but with one only issue maybe it was my mistake  as I didn't clarify it in my question which is that i need to get "Valid stream" result if date in "H" for both matching cells is equal or biger than today() but if one date of them in less than TODAY() then keep both cell as clear **** in your formula it gives me "true" for the cell that has date => TODAY() and keep the other one clear... Can you pplease fix that issue? - thank you sooo much

Please read : Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Do you mean result like this?

A formula in J5:
=IF((COUNTIF($E$5:$E$12,$E$5:$E$12)>1)*($H$5:$H$12>TODAY()),"Valid stream","")

It is a dynamic formula in a new Excel, in earlier versions requires Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
Another variant requires all dates to be >=TODAY().

A formula in J5:
=IF(COUNTIFS($E$5:$E$12,$E$5:$E$12,$H$5:$H$12,">=" & TODAY())>1,"Valid stream","")

3rd attempt. Formula for a table and with requirement for all dates to be >=TODAY()
=IF((COUNTIFS([Code],@[Code],[Issue Date],">=" & TODAY())>1)*(COUNTIFS([Code],@[Code],[Issue Date],">=" & TODAY())=COUNTIF([Code],@[Code])),"Valid stream","")



I do appreciate your help but if gives me #SPILL error  - However my office version is 2021 is that ok? and what can i do  to fix spill error?

Excel version is OK. This is dynamic version. #SPILL error means you have no place for the formula to spill. You enter formula in 1 cell and all cells below should be empty.

I have tested the formula in a separate sheet - it works but unfortunately it give me true value regardless the date value in "H" < or > from TODAY() **** what i need simply if tow cells in the column E have the same value and date in H = or > today in for both cells, so to give me "Valid Stream" text, otherwise keep in blank

thank you for your help  I have fixed the #SPILL error but still one more issue ... the formula gives me "Valid Stream" result while there is only one date cell in "H" for the matches is => TODAY() not both matches - I need to be true if both matches otherwise No to be emplty

I don't really understand. Give me an example. In my screenshot above, the value "d" in column E occurred twice, once with the date 4.09, which was <TODAY() and the second time with the date 6.09, which was >=TODAY() and both results are empty.

I did the same exactly but I get ture result even if only one value with date>+TODAY() - can you please tell me how to send a file to you?.. Sorry I disturbed you too much

Take a screenshot of the worksheet along with the formula you used in the same way as I did in my answer. Mark (e.g. with color) the results that are incorrect.

OK I edited the question with adding screenshot and please note that I will use the formual in a lage table with 351 row for now and i add new rows every day so I don't need the row number to be fixed or limited

also please note that when I convert the small range that I shared in the screenshot to table or copy the formula to my big table I get #SPILL error while the formula work outside the table

So now you expect (in your new screenshot) that there are no valid streams. Don't you? You used formula from my first attempt. Should be: =IF(COUNTIFS($E$5:$E$14,$E$5:$E$14,$H$5:$H$14,">=" & TODAY())>1,"Valid stream","")

You cannot use spilled formulas in Excel tables, only in ranges. If you need to use it in a table should be another variant, which produces only one value at a time.

actually the other formula is the one working good so far but with the issue that i sent to you and this one gives error - HOWEVER yes I want to use the formula in table pleaaaaaaaaaaase

There is also the issue of these repetitions. Is the stream valid if all dates are >= TODAY() or if >1 date is >=TODAY()?

to make it little clear for your goodself I have a  huge table to record permits for workers to enter the buildings units, each unit can only has two worker at the same time but only one to enter and the other one to replace him in vacations . these workers are changeble all the times so the unit number can be repeated many times.  the permit expires every month or when the owner hiers a new one.  so I need the sheet to give me a note "valid streanm" when there are two workers have valid permits for the same unit because i collect the note in other sheet to print the permit

off course many cells in "H" may have date value >= TODAY() but off course for different unit number in "E" not more than two rows with valid date for each unit

Does what I proposed as a third attempt meet your expectations? If not, then keep figuring it out, you already have a lot of material to rework. The description must be precise in terms of the data you use in the table. I cannot interpret your verbal description from the previous comment in terms of this data.

thank you so much I do appreciate your efforts to help and being patient..  the image you shared is exactly what I need  if it work you saved my life then ...but sorry I'm little confused because when I copy the above formula and add it to my table it appears like text

finally I got it =IF(AND(COUNTIFS($E$5:$E$100,E5,$H$5:$H$100,">="&TODAY())>1,H5>=TODAY()),"Valid Stream","")  - but I do really appreciate your help and being patient

In order to check if a cell (like "D1") matches any cell, like in column "E", you might do the following:
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("$D$1";E:E;0))

(where 0 stands for "exact match")
Obviously, you might replace the entire column "E:E" by more precise values, like "E$5:E$3000", but beware: you will always find "E5" in "E5:E3000" :-)

thank you you are right and also I don't mean only E5 but if any cell in E equal other cell in the same coulmn E ....    so can you please write for me the full formula with ANDIF(AND($E5=E:E,$H5>TODAY(),"Valid Stream"))
